# Loading jars just when it needed

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet when is loaded it comes with several jars, but most of them will just be used if the user selects some functionalities of the applet.
I'd like to know if there is any way just to download those jars when the user selects those functions and accelerate the initial loading of the applet?

Comment: JVM will not attempt to compile a class until needed

Comment: But my problem is the download of the Jars, that takes some time to download all of them. And we didn't need all of them most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). Mark the Jars as a 'lazy' download in the JNLP.